# Getting error while using jQuery Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have seen many answers to this question.  But, none of them is working for me.
I have a form with two text fields `uname` and `upass`. On submitting the form, I use the  following ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userForm').submit(function(){
        var myformData = JSON.stringify($("#userForm").serializeArray());
        alert(myFormData);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php', 
         // data: $(this).serializeArray()
         data : myFormData,
         dataType : "json",
         contentType: "application/json"
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Posting failed." );
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I post (click submit), nothing is happening on either client side or server side.

When I use `$(this).serializeArray()`, I am able to get the standard format `key1=value1&key2=value2`.

My php code `login.php` is:

```
<?php
print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
error_log(file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

I am not sure, where I am making mistake.

**UPDATE**

```
<form id='userForm'>
    <div><input type='text' name='uname' placeholder='User' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='upass' placeholder='Password' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>
<!-- where the response will be displayed -->
<div id='response'></div>
```

Comment: @Dave that is not the case. `print` and `echo` have similar features. print_r: *Prints human-readable information about a variable.* This would print to the HTML. The issue is that it the same dataType as the Ajax es expecting. And I suspect the output is what OP is expecting.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If truly nothing happens on the client side, then maybe your `#userForm` is not being found. If you do get the alert, go open the console, head for network analysis and see whether a request is send, where the request is send to and what the response is and include those infos in your question

Comment: `#userForm` is the id of the form. `alert` is not working.  By the way, reading jQuery [doc](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), I am able to get without using `JSON.sringify()`method.  But the problem is I am getting `[object, Object], [Object, Object]`.  The code is almost complete and minimal as I could not type `html` code.

Comment: If the alert is nor working, check if your form looks like `<form id="userForm" ...>` and not `<form id="#userForm" ...>` the # only belongs into the selector to signify it is an id, not in the attribute, since the attribute already shows it is an id. Another possibility could be that your form is loaded dynamically after the original page load. It is hard to tell without at least a minimal html

Comment: Sorry, form id is only  `userForm`. I made a typo.  The form is statically loaded.

Comment: Does your console show an error in line 3?

Comment: Nothing. Neither console error not alert pop up window.

Comment: Your error most likely is in your HMTL then. You need to add your html code to the answer.

Comment: Updated the question with html code. I have used type text for password field. Please ignore it.  Just for testing purpose.

Comment: Ok, there we go. I do believe your form does require an action attribute, even if it is empty, otherwise no submit event will be triggered.

Comment: Modified to `<form id="userForm" action="">`. No  use.  But from the  beginning,I am getting the form data along with the  URL. `post-example.php?uname=hello&upass=world`